# How to interpolate between two pictures of the latent space using StyleGAN2

Tags: python, tensorflow, stylegan

I'm trying to interpolate between two pictures of the latent space using this implementation of StyleGan2 : https://github.com/justinpinkney/stylegan2.git

Here's how i'm projecting my 2 original pictures to the latent space.
From there I would like to interpolate between out_img1 and out_img2

```
proj = projector.Projector(vgg16_pkl)
proj.set_network(Gs)
proj.start(img1)

for i in range(400):
  proj.step()
  lat1 = proj.get_dlatents()
  latent_seq1.append(lat1)

out_img1 = generate_images(lat1,Gs)

proj2 = projector.Projector(vgg16_pkl)
proj2.set_network(Gs)
proj2.start(img2)

for i in range(400):
  proj2.step()
  lat2 = proj2.get_dlatents()
  latent_seq2.append(lat2)

out_img2 = generate_images(lat2,Gs)
```

Comment: Do you get "name Gs is not defined"? Trying to solve for this